# Is there a name for a vector space together with a bilinear form?

Tags: terminology, bilinear-form

I know about inner product spaces, but I need to consider a more general setting:

An $F$-vector space $V$ together with a bilinear function $V\times V\to F$.

Is there some name for this that is commonly used?

Comment: http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/signature.pdf     for a start.

Comment: I would use "bilinear space." A closely related question (about symmetric bilinear forms) was asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525847/terminology-how-do-we-call-a-vector-space-equipped-with-a-symmetric-bilinear-fo/

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think I will use "bilinear space"!

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I've seen is "semi-indefinite-inner product space" (https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4872) which does not require the bilinear function to be symmetric or positive, but does impose a non-degeneracy condition and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

As Will points out there is also "quadratic space," if your bilinear function is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you for the link and for comparing the two definitions (semi-indefinite-inner product space and quadratic space)!